# How to get users old and new email id in one organizational unit using Google Directory API whome username or primary email ID has been updated

Tags: java, google-apps, google-account, google-directory-api, google-reporting-api

I have requirement to get the users list from Google Directory

I need to get the list of all the users  where the primary email address has been changed due to change of last name or initials, find out the Old email address and new as well with updated date.

I have already connectivity with Google Directory API using Java. Currently I can get all the users from my organization.

Comment: Have you googled it? Try to do it yourself, and if you run into any __compiling problems__, we may help you out.

Comment: Can you add any details like: code used, error problem encountered? [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) Show the community what you have tried.